# Windows services git pull issue

Tags: git, service

I have a complex process going:

- I wrote a nodejs service
- I turned this into a windows service that executes cmd commands
- Part of these commands is a `git pull`
- The `git pull` doesn't do anything. And because it is a windows service, I cannot see what the error message for the `git pull` is

I thought of trying to export the output to a text file but it doesn't work (it just inserts an empty line). I have tried all of these:

- `git pull >> "...myfile.txt"`
- `git pull 2>> "...myfile.txt"`
- `git pull &>> "...myfile.txt"`
- `git pull 2>&1 | tee "...myfile.txt"`

My question: **why does `git pull` not work through a windows service cmd command OR how can I view the ENTIRE cmd process so that I can see what is going on**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service is probably running as different user.

Executing `git pull` command will fail if the user:

- doesn't have git.exe in the PATH
- is not authorized to access the repository you are pulling
- etc

Change it to your account in:
`Start Menu -> Services -> [your service] -> Properties -> Log On tab`

Note: you may want to restart your machine after the change

Comment: Ok so I added my logon stuff and it didn't work until I restarted the pc (just restarting the service doesn't work). Just add this to your answer please...but I would like to ask, how do I give everyone on the pc access to this repository without doing the whole logon thing? I don't want the service to rely on my user's logon details

Comment: I have updated my answer.
In your follow-up question you are asking to let other users use your credentials, which is not recommended. By default git uses windows credential manager (`Control Panel - Credential Manager`), associated with your windows user account and encrypted. If you still want to share git credentials with other users, exposing your username and password, you could use file store [https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store]
Use absolute path to the file as explained here https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2017/09/25/how-to-setup-git-credential-store-in-windows/)

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for the explanations :)